# Do any FPGAs that set undefined values ​in registers after power up exist?

Tags: fpga, pll, programmable-logic, power-up-conditions

There is some discussions how to set default values or start an initial sequence in FPGAs design after programming/power-up.

- The most reliable method is using a supervisor IC which guaranteed send the reset signal. But this method needs a descrete IC on the board. Many boards haven't such supervisor.
- Less reliable method is usind a PLL lock signal for reset. But some small FPGAs (CPLDs) have not a PLL. The other counter argument is that if a PLL will fail for some clocks it cause not only skipping these clocks but the whole reinitializing of the FPGAs design.
- The other method is using some register with known default value to detect power-up condition and then changing this value. But if the registers default values are undefined this method did't work.

Do any FPGAs that set undefined values ​​in registers after power up exist? Are there any examples of such FPGAs?

Comment: All FPGA I know of have their own Power-Up-Reset and start with precisely those values loaded to FF that are generated by the synthesis tool. (Synthesis may give seemingly random behavior if initial values are not given)

Comment: Another power up reset source  - use the "configuration done" (or equiv) that the FPGA will likely provide from its own power on reset generation to trigger a power on reset circuit in the user design.

Comment: Which goes first, the end of configuration or the edge on the CONF_DONE pin? If the edge is the last, is a delay between the end of configuration and the edge enough to detect the edge by the FPGA design? Have you come across a similar design? If yes is there such board schematic in public domain?

Comment: The datasheet of your FPGA gives you a detailed description of the sequence. In some cases you can even select which sequence you like to have.

Comment: @asdfex "In some cases you can even select which sequence you like to have" can you give an example of this cases?

Comment: @Tom Carpenter "Another power up reset source - use the "configuration done"". As they say in the "Cyclone IV Device Handbook" (vol.1 pg.200-201) there is a 300us delay between the CONF_DONE edge and the enter to the user mode. There is an INIT_DONE pin in this FPGAs. But it send rising edge simultaneously with the user mode enter. So a FPGA design can't feel this edge. Did you see any examples of a FPGA design reset which connect to CONF_DONE?

Comment: Antifuse or flash-based parts could possibly act like this.  It's also possible that things like internal RAMs may not be initialized on certain devices - URAM on Xilinx devices is 0 initialized, but I read something recently about a particular integrated RAM on a different device not being initialized at all during config.